# OnActivityResult ()

Tags: java, android, methods

I have code which should allow me to take value from calculator and use it further:

```
//-----------------This section creates the keypad functionality
for (int o = 0; o < keybuttons.length; o++) {
    final int n = o;
    keybuttons[o] = (Button) findViewById(data.keyIds[n]);
    keybuttons[o].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String tmp = texts[selectEdit].getText()
                    .toString();
                switch (n) {
                case 3:
                    texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 1));
                    break; //get cursor position and delete char
                case 7:
                    {
                        // Create intent for RealCalc.
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent("uk.co.quarticsoftware.REALCALC");
                        double x = 0; // Set initial value (double).
                        if (!texts[selectEdit].getText()
                            .toString()
                            .equals("")) {
                            x = Double.valueOf(texts[selectEdit].getText()
                                .toString());
                        }
                        intent2.putExtra("X", x);
                        // Launch calculator
                        try {
                            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
                            try {
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException f) {
                                // Google Play Store app not available.
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    } //open Calculator
                case 11:
                    {
                        if (!tmp.contains("E")) texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp + "" + keybuttons[n].getText());
                        break;
                    } //check for E if dont have do default case
                case 15:
                    {
                        TL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    } //simulate back button
                default:
                    {
                        texts[selectEdit].setText(tmp + "" + keybuttons[n].getText());
                        //get cursor start and end and get entire String
                        // replace selected String with button text
                        //insert back
                        break;
                    }
                } //end of switch
            } //end of try
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("market://details?id=uk.co.nickfines.RealCalc"));
                // Calculator not installed
            } //calculator.num=n;
            catch (Exception e) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                EasyPhysActivity.error = sw.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // User pressed OK.
                double value = data.getDoubleExtra("X", Double.NaN);
                if (Double.isNaN(value)) {
                    // Calculation result was "Error".
                } else {
                    // Calculation result ok.
                }
            } else {
                // User pressed cancel or back button.
            }
        }
    });

}
//----------------------------------------
```

But it doesn't like these three lines:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

If I delete `@Override` it becomes better, but it still shows an error for

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

What is going wrong in here?

Comment: What is the error? And please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: It gives an error in three lines which I repeatedly wrote down in the bottom

Comment: Please post the *error message* in addition to the code that causes the error.

Comment: The error is "void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override `onActivityResult` inside `OnClickListener` because it does not exist in the base class.  Move your `onActivityResult` code so that it is inside your `Activity` class, not the `OnClickListner`.

Comment: But I can't do it, because I need that calculator would launch in case 7

Comment: @L.G. I said nothing about moving the `Intent` that launches the calculator, just the definition of the on `OnActivityResult` method, it must belong to an `Activity` otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @L.G. I think you misunderstand. `onActivityResult` is called *after* your calculator finishes. It has nothing to do with launching the calculator in the first place.

Comment: I tried to movie it out of OnClickListener, but it still gives this error "void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult"

Comment: @L.G.  Then you still have it in the wrong scope, sounds like you moved it out of the `OnClickListner` and into a method definition.  It should be defined at the same level as `onCreate`