# onActivityResult not called after taking picture

Tags: java, android, android-camera

How know that subject is well documented and I have read a lot on that issue, but I still have the following problem: when I take a picture with my app and click on "validate" button, nothing occur. The aime of what I am doing: passing to onActivityReult function not only the thumbnail, but the "whole" picture taken by the camera.

Here is the listener as defined for the "take a picture" button:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraTest");
            mediaStorageDir.mkdir(); // make sure you got this folder
            Log.i("Report",mediaStorageDir.toString());
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

            try
            {
                //create directories and the file
                mediaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                mediaFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.e("Report", "create error for file "+mediaFile);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
            Log.i("Report","Uri: "+mFileUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);// this line causes issue - onActivityResult not called...
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}
});
```

and here is the onActivityResult method... that is never called (and that is not declared in the onClickListener method):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("Report", "1");
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            try {
                String[] projection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
                String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + 
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;
                String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";
                Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, selection, null, sort);
                Log.d("Report", "3");
                long imageId = 0l;
                long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
                String thumbnailPath = "";

                try {
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();
                    imageId = myCursor
                            .getLong(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
                    thumbnailImageId = myCursor
                            .getLong(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
                    thumbnailPath = myCursor
                            .getString(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                } finally {
                    myCursor.close();
                }

                String[] largeFileProjection = {
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

                String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
                        + " DESC";
                myCursor = this.managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
                String largeImagePath = "";

                try {
                    myCursor.moveToFirst();

                    // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of the
                    // image.
                    largeImagePath = myCursor
                            .getString(myCursor
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                            largeImagePath));

                } finally {
                    // myCursor.close();
                }
                Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(imageId));
                Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

                Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uriThumbnailImage);
                Bitmap image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uriLargeImage);
```

But, as said in the title, onActivityResult is not called. Could you please find out why? Because I have tried almost everything I have found on that subject but I should have missed something.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure it's not called? Have you checked it with debugger?

Comment: First line of the onActivityResult method is a print, and I have nothing in the logcat

Comment: I asked it because logcat sometimes leaves out messages.

Comment: agreed with @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem. check whether other logcat messages are printed or not.

Comment: please remove super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); (2nd line) from your onActivityResult() function.

Comment: Yes. Use the debugger to check it. Place a breakpoint at the first line of onActivityResult and see if it's fired. (Press Ctrl+Shift+B or Cmd+Shift+B (on a mac) to toggle line breakpoint in Eclipse.)

Comment: The point is that nothing happend when I click on the "validate" button of the camera, that also makes me think that onActivityResult method is not triggered. In any case, I'll do the check you sugested right now.

Comment: I have removed the line super.onActivityResult and GREAT, the method is called. But I'm still facing some issues I will describe in that post if I do not find the answer by myself. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

check if you have declared the right permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and be sure the file you want to write into exists:
add this below `puc_img = new File(photo,"Puc_Img.jpg");`

```
try
{
    //create directories and the file
    puc_file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    puc_file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

Comment: I do have these lines

Comment: as far as i know, the file has to exists before you can take a picture, so give the above code a try :) - ive updated it further to provide a existing directory to create the file

Comment: just a question : how do you init puc_file?

Comment: this is an addition to your code. put it right below `puc_img = new File(photo,"Puc_Img.jpg");`

Comment: Rrraaaah. Ok. So that's what I had done. Since I am just using photo var, I removed all occurences of puc_img. I edited the code accordingly in the basis question. But now, I am still not able to trigger onActivityResult method. What did I do wrong?

Comment: hmm that seems very courious to me.. try to place a logger before `super.onActivityResult(...) and see if this changes anything, but to be honest, i dont this so :(

Comment: I removed the onActivityResult() line, it solved my issue before to do the changes on the file creation...

Comment: I changed the code to the one edited once again. Sorry for all the changes. But according to this, I am entering in the onActivityResult. The issue, now, is that the picture seems not to be taken. Why? Because the snapshot I see after taking the picture is not the one just taken but the last "valid" I succeeded to take. Any idea? And btw, I have a "Grow heap (frag case) to 21.432MB" while sending the picture, but I don't think that this is related.

Comment: Ok, if something comes to you in the middle of the night... Feel free to update the post!

Comment: its just 6 PM here in Germany, but i'll do if i imagine a solution :)

Comment: Wrong, you don't need Camera permission to use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE via Intent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code but you could be declaring `onActivityResult` within your `onClickListener`. If that's true you need to move it. 
Take a look at this answer:

[OnActivityResult ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783758/onactivityresult)

Comment: No, the onActivityResult method is not declared in the onClickListener :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to solve that issue, I used some "trick" detailed here:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraTest");
            mediaStorageDir.mkdir(); // make sure you got this folder
            Log.i("Report",mediaStorageDir.toString());
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

            try
            {
                //create directories and the file
                mediaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                mediaFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.e("Report", "create error for file "+mediaFile);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tmpFilePath = mediaFile.getPath();
            mFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
            Log.i("Report","Uri: "+mFileUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }

    });
```

So then, I am recovering the file stored in the tmpFilePath, by using that method in the onActivityResult function:

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.tmpFilePath);
```

And... It's working fine. I still have some issues when sending the file to the WS but that very question have been solved by that piece of code. Thanks for the help, you put me on the track :)